# Reset count on icon badge

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I send pushes using Parse.com. When i send pushes i set increment badge to "yes" so users can see badges with "1" on my app icon.

When users opens app's main ViewController, app clears badge count using this code

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0
```

This works fine and badge is clear. But when i send new push with badge increment enabled - i see that number on badge is 2. Is something wrong with my way to reset badge count?

Comment: something is wrong with new push badge number.

Comment: In your installations class (In parse), their will be an installation object against that device. On that object, there is a variable for badge count. Once you clear the badge from the app, don't forget to remove it from the backend as well.

Comment: @NSNoob how to perform it in swift?

Comment: @moonvader I don't work in swift. I have added the general idea. Convert it to swift and feel free to edit the answer as per swift. (Though I think that answer will work in swift). Add that snippet to swift equivalent of `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` or `didBecomeActive` in app delegate, wherever you are resetting your local badge count.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because while you remove the local badge, the badge count in Parse Installation class for that device remains the same. You can do the following to remove that:

Assuming that you have already made sure that current user has a PFInstallation (i.e. he did not decline the push notification access request) , To reset the badge number on backend, you can use the following:

```
var currentInstallation = PFInstallation.currentInstallation()
      if currentInstallation.badge != 0 {
        currentInstallation.badge = 0
        currentInstallation.save
       }
```

This makes sure to set the badge to 0 only if it is currently showing a non-zero counter.

Setting badge on `currentInstallation` will automatically set applicationIconBadgeNumber too. By doing this, Parse will know what number your app is currently displaying and they can increment the counter correctly whenever an Increment is sent to this device again. For more information you can read [Official Parse Blog Announcement](http://blog.parse.com/announcements/badge-management-for-ios/) on this matter.